# SqlDataSource, 3rd dropdown in chain fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

[Registration form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYe6H.jpg)

**[This is working fine.  I had wrong information to test with.  I will leave up because it is the way to do cascading DDL's using SQLDataSource  albeit outdated]**

My primary language is C# but the application is in VB.Net.  I have appointment application students sitting for individual and group portraits on college campuses.  The registration page has three dropdown lists: 
 (1) college Campuses, (2) Organizations that belong to a particular Campus, and a (3) Classification schema that belongs to a particular Organization.  The Campus and Organization dropdown lists work as expected.  The Classification will display the class schema for the first organization on the initial load of the page but will not change after that.  A class schema can be [Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, Senior] or [Undergradutre, Masters, Doctoral, Faculty].  There are other class schemas. There is one class schema per organization.

Running the configure on all Datasource components shows them functioning properly. That is the Classification Data Source shows varying schema depending on the organization parameter entered.  Here is the set up:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CampusSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="spCampusSel" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="OrgSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="spOrgByCampusSel" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CampusDDL" Name="ParentOrg_ID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ClassSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="spClassSchemaByOrgSel" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="OrgDDL" DefaultValue="" Name="OrgID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="CampusDDL" 
    TabIndex="1"
    DataSourceID="CampusSource"
    DataValueField="Org_ID" 
    DataTextField="LongName"
    AutoPostBack="True" 
    RunAt="server"> 
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="OrgDLL" 
    TabIndex="2" 
    DataSourceID="OrgSource" 
    DataTextField="LongName"
    DataValueField="Org_ID" 
    AutoPostBack="True"
    RunAt="server">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ClassDDL" 
    TabIndex="8"
    DataSourceID="ClassSource"
    DataValueField="Class"
    DataTextField="Class"
    AutoPostBack="False"
    runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

According the Microsoft Docs, this is all I need.  But I have also tried setting the ClassSource's parameter value in code at various palaces including the Selecting event. At least I could see that the OrgDDL has the correct organization values (the primary key of the organization).  Thus the correct values were being supplied to the datasource.

```
    Protected Sub DMS_Class_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles DMS_Class.Selecting
         e.Command.Parameters(0).Value = OrgDDL.SelectedValue
    End Sub
```

All SQLDataSources are set to DataSet mode.  The Class Schema store procedure returns 1 column with each class on a row. Such as:

Freshman

Sophomore

Junior

Senior

Comment: The problem is not clear. What is actually happening and what do you expect? Also can you also show the events that you have put for these drop downs to make it clear how the data is being retrieved and assigned ? That would be helpful.

Comment: This is an application inherited from a 2006 time frame I believe.  The only other code originally present are two lines under the If Not Postback statement setting default values.  CampusDDL.SelectedValue = 441, OrgDDL.SelectedIndex = 0,  I will post a photo.  But user selects from Campuses, then selects from Organizations belonging to selected Campus, and picks his Classification from the Classes belonging to select Organization.  For example: University of Oklahoma, Alpha Chi Omega, Sophomore.

Comment: @Akshay Raut My apologies.  It turns out I had wrong data to test with. Out of several hundred organizations, there are only a few with custom class schemas.